# How to remove Dojo Dijit from Spring MVC project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dojo

How to remove Dojo Dijit from javascript call

How can I change the following code to use just a html select we dont want to use dijit or dojo.. Can someone please help us out

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
        elementId : "borough",
        widgetType : "dijit.form.Select",
        widgetAttrs : {
            promptMessage : "Enter Borough",
            required : true, 
            onChange : function() {
                Spring.remoting.submitForm(
                   'submit',
                   'member', 
                   {_eventId: 'loadSchools', fragments:'contents'}
               ); 
        return false;
    } }}));
</script>
```

Comment: Simple answer: delete it. -- But I think if it would be so easy, you won`t ask, so what is you problem, why don`t you just delete it?

Comment: sorry rapph but I still need the post (submit) to work on the change of the selectbox

Answer (score 0):

Delete the Dojo stuff and repace it with plain old pure Java Script: `onchange='this.form.submit()'`:

```
<form ...>
  <select name='someField' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: this will not work Ralph.. I need to set the eventID before for Spring Webflow

Comment: @user2428795: Sorry your question is still much to unclear to provide an answer that helps you